# My Ev3 Brick Doesn't Boot Other Operating Systems

Tags: installation, hardware, lego-mindstorms

everybody. I am having trouble with my ev3 brick because it doesn't seem to boot any other operating systems. I have tried to boot monoware, lejos, and ev3dev on it. When I tried ev3dev first, but get an error message right after it tries to boot. I then tried lejos, and got to installing rootfs and it then stopped. I tried many different methods, and it didn't work. Then I tried monoware and I got to the picture and it just stopped. Then tried lejos again and couldn't get it to start installing. Please help me out. I have put a lot of time and effort into this. It would be nice to find a solution to avoid frustration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have too little reputation to leave a comment, so this answer will have to do.
I recently went through the same struggles of installing LeJOS on my EV3, so I can try to help you. I also had the problem of the installation stopping at "Installing rootfs". What solved it for me was simply trial and error of finding the correct combination between JRE (.tar.gz) and the content of lejosimage.zip (since there are multiple versions of LeJOS).
Also, flashing the sd500.img found in the zip file onto the sd card using an external tool was the final step to get it working.
I can provide you with more information this evening as I get home, but until then I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: Ok, will try. Would you be able to tell what files to use (what JRE, what image?) So do I burn the sd 500 to the drive? Open the sd card creator and select the image and JRE. Then put it in my ev3 brick? I will try this way.

Comment: I tried.It didn't work. Could you maybe give me a few more details? Frustrated.

Comment: I can totally understand your frustration, it also took me about my entire saturday to get it working. But just try to keep motivated, it's so awesome once you get it to work!
Anyways, I took a look at my laptop from which I installed lejos from, but it seems I deleted the folder which I put onto the sd-card, meaning I don't know which JRE and lejos-versions I used. I also don't have access to the robot until tomorrow...
I'm sorry, I'm feeling helples...